# How to address CS8607 warning about DisallowNull?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Consider this C# class in a .NET 5 class library with the [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature *enabled:*

```
public class ContraMapComparer<T, T1> : IEqualityComparer<T1>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> source;
    private readonly Func<T1, T> selector;

    public ContraMapComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> source, Func<T1, T> selector)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public bool Equals(T1? x, T1? y)
    {
        if (x is null && y is null)
            return true;
        if (x is null || y is null)
            return false;

        return source.Equals(selector(x), selector(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] T1 obj)
    {
        return source.GetHashCode(selector(obj));
    }
}
```

The `[DisallowNull]` attribute was added by Visual Studio's *Enable Interface* Quick Action.

When compiling, the compiler emits this warning:

> ```
> CS8607    A possible null value may not be used for a type marked with [NotNull] or [DisallowNull]
> ```

Obviously, if you've enabled *Treat warnings as errors* (which I have) this means that the code doesn't compile.

How does one address this issue?

I've tried adding run-time null guards to `obj`, `source`, and `selector`, but that doesn't help. I've also tried adding the `[DisallowNull]` attribute to both `source` and `selector`, but that also doesn't help.

Reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) for `[DisallowNull]` left me none the wiser.

Even removing the `[DisallowNull]` attribute fails to address the problem. The compiler warning remains even then.

The only fix I've been able to identify is a `#pragma` to suppress the warning:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8607 // A possible null value may not be used for a type marked with [NotNull] or [DisallowNull]
                return source.GetHashCode(selector(obj));
#pragma warning restore CS8607 // A possible null value may not be used for a type marked with [NotNull] or [DisallowNull]
```

Is there any other fix?

Comment: Have you tried using `!`? `return source.GetHashCode(selector(obj)!);` for example. (It's unclear to me which part of the expression is causing the warning - it might be the `selector(obj)` part; you could split it into separate expressions to check.)

Comment: You could - and probably should - also throw if `obj` is `null`.

Comment: Just remove the attribut `DisallowNull`.

Comment: @vernou - in the question - "Even removing the [DisallowNull] attribute fails to address the problem"

Comment: @JonSkeet As I wrote, null guards don't help. I hadn't tried the null-forgiving operator (`!`) which *does* make the warning go away. It's prettier than using `#pragmas`, but is it more than symptomatic relief?

Comment: Have you tried adding a null guard to the *result* of `selector(obj)`?

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do with your type, adding a `where T : notnull` constraint also resolves things.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, that addresses the compiler warning.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, this is a great solution. Why not add it as an answer? I might be inclined to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I appreciate both previous answers for explaining what the problem is, I find none of the suggested solutions optimal.

- [Throwing an exception in `GetHashCode` is forbidden](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode). (Not quite official documentation, but with Eric Lippert, it's close enough.)
- Using a custom delegate makes the API less portable.

Fortunately, Jeroen Mostert suggested a better solution in the comments: Constrain `T` to be `notnull`:

```
public class ContraMapComparer<T, T1> : IEqualityComparer<T1> where T : notnull
```

That's what I did, and that addressed the problem.

Comment: Ín general I don't think the comparer should require additional constraints. You cant use it in e.g. a `List<T1?>`   I would just rewrite the gethashcode to test if the selector returns null and if it does return a 0.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is not talking about the `[DisallowNull]` attribute on your `GetHashCode` method's parameter. It is talking about the `source.GetHashCode` call! After all, this call is also calling `IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode`, which has the `[DisallowNull]` attribute.

`selector(obj)` returns a `T`, but `T` has no constraints on it, so it could be a nullable type, like `string?` or `int?`. And if it were a nullable type, it could be null. But `source.GetHashCode` does not allow nulls! Hence the warning.

> I've tried adding run-time null guards to `obj`, `source`, and `selector`

You should be checking `selector(obj)`, not `source`, `selector`, or `obj`. `selector(obj)` is the thing that can be null, and is not allowed to be null here.

```
T t = selector(obj);
if (t == null) {
    throw new ArgumentException("obj maps to a null!", nameof(obj));
}
return source.GetHashCode(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Func<T1,T>` isn't annotated to not return `null`. Introduce a new delegate that does support that:

```
[return:NotNull]
public delegate T NonNullFunc<in T1, out T>(T1 value);
public class ContraMapComparer<T, T1> : IEqualityComparer<T1>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> source;
    private readonly NonNullFunc<T1, T> selector;

    public ContraMapComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> source, NonNullFunc<T1, T> selector)
    {
    //As before
```

This is better than forgiving nulls or using pragmas since it should enforce that whatever expression is used to define `selector`, it will not return `null`.

(You may wish to also annotate the input parameter to the delegate to disallow nulls)

Comment: The obvious drawback here is a new public type `NonNullFunc`. This is fine for `ContraMapComparer`, but fails to scale across types, especially from different authors (imagine having to deal with a `NotNullFunc` as well, and of course `NonNullFunc` from a different assembly). It's also not a very nice interface for clients if they're used to consistently passing `Func`s around, since there are no implicit conversions.

Comment: If we did want to express that `ContraMapComparer` only deals with non-`null` `T`s, simply adding it as a type constraint is probably better. If we have to keep open the option of `null` `T`s, even a separate `NonNullContraMapComparer` is probably better than a new delegate (since it won't clash with anything), though properly sharing implementations would probably be painful.